# "Calling" UI activity method from a class

Tags: android

I have an Activity which mainly handles the UI, and I do most of the rest from another class (not a service). One of the things I do from that class is playing audio. What I need to do is tell my Activity when the audio finished playing (OnCompletionListener).

```
public class MyClass implements OnCompletionListener {
          private MyActivity activity = new MyActivity();
public MyClass(){
}
 ...........
 ...........
 ...........
@Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        activity.onComplete();

    }

}
```

This is wrong because "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method onComplete() from the type MyActivity.

I'm pretty sure I'm using Java wrong, but I cant figure out how to call onComplete from the class. (changing onComplete to static isn't posible).

EDIT:
added a constructor to MyActivity:

```
public MyActivity(){

    }
```

and created an instance of MyActivity, activity (see the edited code above), passed it to the method, but when I do `activity.onComplete();` it stops unexpectedly. (I dont know why my logcat isnt working, I'll post back when I get it to work)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass an instance of MyActivity to MyClass and call a method on it. It's arguable approach but best I can suggest having information that you provided.

Comment: It Throwed me a Stackoverflow(funny) error at MyClass:private MyActivity activity = new MyActivity(); and on MyActivity when I created an Instance of MyClass (which I had before all this problem, and cant remove it).

Comment: Activities can't be created via constructor, sorry. They are created by OS.

Comment: Typically you would be in your activity when you create MyClass so just pass `this`.